# Wordpress - Pulling just 4 images from a repeater field within a loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I wondered if someone could help me with something that is probably quite simple when you know how.

I'm creating a game based website and I'm just working on the directory page where a list of all the games will be shown. I'm using a plug-in called '[Advanced Custom Fields](http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/advanced-custom-fields/)' to create all my custom fields for each game.

At the moment I'm running a loop to pull in each game :-

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'games', 'posts_per_page' => 10)); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

And then within this loop calling for different custom fields of the game (title, screenshots, description, download buttons etc...). But I have a problem when it comes to the screenshots, I can happily grab all the screenshots, but I just want to pull out 4. I've searched around all the threads, looked through the documentation, hit google, but whatever method I've tried I haven't achieved any success yet :(

My current code within the above loop for pulling out the screenshots is :-

```
<?php if(get_field('screenshots')): ?>
<ul class="screenshots">
<?php while (the_repeater_field('screenshots')): ?>

    <li><a href="<?php the_sub_field('large_screenshot'); ?>" data-fancybox-group="button" class="fancybox"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('thumbnail_screenshot'); ?>" title="<?php the_sub_field('screenshot_title'); ?>"/></a></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul> <!--- end of screenshots !-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is there a way to just limit my results to a total of 4 instead of displaying all available screenshots? A random 4 would be an even nicer option, but isn't paramount.

I'm sure the solution is far simpler than some of the things I've tried without success so far.

Many thanks for any help received.

Cheers

Rob

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the plugin you are using. but a simple solution would be using a counter like this:

```
<?php $i=0; ?>
<?php while (the_repeater_field('screenshots')): ?>

<li><a href="<?php the_sub_field('large_screenshot'); ?>" data-fancybox-group="button" class="fancybox"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('thumbnail_screenshot'); ?>" title="<?php the_sub_field('screenshot_title'); ?>"/></a></li>

<?php if($i<4) $i++;
      else break; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, much appreciated.

Sadly adding the above just causes the page not to load, I've googled leading off of this answer but haven't been able to produce a working result.

The ? and : in the final statement cause the page to not load, these as ; and the page goes though, but obviously not achieving what is needed and only actually displaying one result.

Any idea on an adaption of the above that might work?

Thanks again,

Rob

Comment: Thanks again, I think this is progress :) 

Page is now loading & it's affecting the screenshots, but not as expected though because it's also affecting the download buttons, which is the final <?php if;?> and </php while;?> in the loop. So is there a way to contain this statement to this one section?

So changing the number ($i<4) will produce different results based on how many screenshots are uploaded & how many download buttons.

Inputting ($i<3) for e.g. displays 4 screenshots if there are 2 download buttons related, Im sure there is logic to this, but I just can't wrap my head around it

Answer (score 0):

I am curious as to how you got more than 1 loop to run, by definition it should work like you're experience but for some reason when I post the same concept I can only get the while to produce one result even though there are 10 images.

```
while(the_repeater_field('horse_images')): 
    $image_id = get_sub_field('image');
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,medium);
    echo '<img src="'.$image_src[0].'">';
endwhile;
```

I wonder if it would work if you modified your code like with **&& $i <= 4**

```
<?php if(get_field('screenshots')): ?>
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<ul class="screenshots">
   <?php while (the_repeater_field('screenshots') && $i <= 4 ): ?>

   <li><a href="<?php the_sub_field('large_screenshot'); ?>" data-fancybox-group="button" class="fancybox"><img src="<?php the_sub_field('thumbnail_screenshot'); ?>" title="<?php the_sub_field('screenshot_title'); ?>"/></a></li>

   $i++
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I figured out my own problem, I for some reason made 10 unique image FIELDS rather than just one field and set the ROW limit to 10 (which I had done this in the settings but because of the confusion in the post I'm testing with I only inserted 1 row hence my looping issue, must admit I feel a little dumb there.

Hope you were able to resolve your issue with that small insert

Answer (score 0):

Look:

```
<?php if( have_rows('gallery_img') ): ?>
  <div class="gl-images">
    <div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
      <?php $i=0; ?>
      <?php while( have_rows('gallery_img') ): the_row(); 
        // vars
        $image = get_sub_field('img_item');
      ?>
      <?php if( $image): ?>
        <li class="slide">
          <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
        </li>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if($i>1) $i++;
        else break; 
      ?>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
     </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: could you explain your answer with a few more details?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (have_rows('service_priceing')): ?>
<?php $n=0; while (have_rows('service_priceing')): the_row(); ?>
<?php $package = get_sub_field('package'); ?>
<?php $rent = get_sub_field('rent'); ?>
<?php $price = get_sub_field('price'); ?>
<div class="columns price-columns">
   <ul class="price">
      <li class="header" style="background-color:<?php if($n==1){ echo "Red"; }else{echo "Blue";}?>"><?php echo $package; ?></li>
      <li class="dates">
         <p><?php echo $rent; ?></p>
      </li>



   </ul>
</div>
<?php $n++; if($n == 3){ break; } endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```